# Assigning background color and text-color of button in HTML style

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a button and trying to give to style properties for it in the same html statement but not getting the correct output.

```
<button style="color:yellow" style="background-color:blue" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
```

I want to give text color as yellow and background color as blue in this html code only without using any kind of css. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep all of your style properties in a single tag and separate them with semi-colons.

```
<button style="color:yellow; background-color:blue;" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **style** only once. Use a semicolon between each properties.

```
<button style="color:yellow; background-color:blue;" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to assign a class to it and enter the required values there

```
 <button class="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

then in its css file

```
.btn{
 background-color:blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```css
.BtnStyle
{
color:yellow; 
background-color:blue;
font-size:30px;

}
```

```html
<button class="BtnStyle"  type="button" onclick="alert('Btn Class Style Sample!')">Please Click!</button>
```